# Link Up/Down using VB script in windows 2019

Tags: vbscript, wmi, wmi-query

I have tried to use the Enable() method from Win32_NetworkAdapter and Win32_PnPEntity class. But it only enable or disable the interface.

```
        Set devices = WMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE DeviceID like '" & Replace(adapter.PNPDeviceId, "\", "\\") & "'")
        For Each dev In devices
            Return_En = dev.Enable()
            if Return_En <> 0 Then
                Wscript.StdOut.WriteLine "Failed to bring up the interface, error code " & Return_En
            End if
```

I wanted to make the link up or down and not to Disable/Enable. This is a custom feature of a particular NIC card. In simple words, i wanted to control a custom property of a card via VBScript.

[image]

Is there a way to control this property from VB script.?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reset Network Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35249238/reset-network-adapter)

Comment: No, this is what exactly i am doing. I need to control a particular property of the card from VB script (no powershell is available in my enviornment)

Comment: Who mentioned anything about PowerShell?

Comment: No, That's just FYI.

Comment: What is Windows 2019?